# Should I disable Cloud Build and GCR after building an app on Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am a first time cloud user:

I have created an application using Docker Image, then stored it in Google Container Registry (GCR) and then deployed it in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). Now the application is working fast and properly. I was wondering what service should I disable after that?
Because, to make this project, I have enabled Cloud Build API and Container Registry API. Should I disable those services? And after disabling those services, will me application stops?

Comment: No, do not disable those services. Yes, at some point your application will stop working because the service will not be able to fetch the container. The APIs do not cost you anything. The cost of storing containers is very small (pennies per GB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud is pay per use and **GCP** is also which you are using.

You will be charged of the usage only enabling the API won't cost much. Plus **Container Registry** **API** disabling this API can create the issue for application **docker** image to **pull** and **push**.

Keep them as it is, so you don't have to enable everytime when you build the image of the application again.